# jQuery's .removeClass() doesn't update CSS in DOM on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css

Changes I make to the classes of a div using jQuery's `.removeClass()` do not affect the CSS.

I have this:

```
<div class="nav active">Menu Item</div>
```

then I do

```
$('.nav').removeClass('active');
```

The CSS for the `.active` class has a background image. It remains even after this is fired off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The concept of removing a CSS class with jQuery works fine so there must be other things going on that you are not showing us.  Can you distill this down to an actual running example that shows the problem and perhaps include the actual CSS and all the actual relevant javascript?  One frequent source of these issues is a javascript error before your line of code executes.

Comment: Can you provide more context?  I've never encountered this issue and it could be some other side effect.

Comment: Can you post an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: this is works fine http://jsfiddle.net/jJfdr/3/ whats your problem?

Comment: This works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, etc as it should...just when viewing on my LG Android and iPhone, the CSS background-position doesn't change back to just plain 'nav' class

Comment: this guy seems to have a similar issue with no answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264130/jquery-addclass-on-mousedown-mobile-touch-browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the same issue that I was facing.
You can just change the class attribute.
Example `$('.nav').attr('class','nav');`

removeClass wont work in iOs, and some mobile devices. This works

Comment: This is also causing same issue, Did't work. 
Issue is coming once from 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by including `myscript.js` after `jquery.mobile.js` in my HTML file. Hope that works!